# What is wrong with this drush command in Drupal 7 Ubercart 3 to delete orders in bulk via command line?

Tags: 7, ubercart, drush

I am trying to delete my Ubercart 3 orders in bulk via the command line with just a one liner:

```
for XX in {1..12}; do drush ev 'uc_order_delete($XX)' -v; done;
```

It beats having to do it via the bulk operations in views. I'm not sure whats wrong with my command as it says I have an Undefined variable when i put $XX in quotes.

Comment: Replace single quotes with double quotes

Answer (score 0):

You've to use double quotes instead of single quotes, so variables retain their special meaning.

Read more:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash